# Could someone explain how fork works?

Tags: c, unix, fork, posix

I don't really understand how fork() works.I understand examples with one fork,but when there are more than one call I don't.I have an example like this and it prints 4 lines of hello, how many processes are created?

```c
int main(void)
{
       fork();
       fork();
       printf("hello\n");

       return 0;
}
```

Comment: See this wiki for an overview of fork and example in C: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After `fork()` call,  both processes (original and spawned) continue to execute from next line of code. So both processes execute second `fork()` instruction, so in the end you have **4** processes. Hence you see 4 instances of `"hello"` lines printed.

One picture is worth a thousand words:

[image: fork illustrated]

Answer (score 3):

The `fork()` syscall essentially creates a "clone" of the process executing it. Both "clones" run almost identically (except for the return value of `fork()`).
The first call to fork() is executed by one process (let's call that one "P"), which creates a second process "C". Now there are two processes, which both execute the second line in your main() function. So **both** processes, P and C, create a new process. This is why you end up with a total of 4 processes, all of which print "hello" exactly once.

The following example might make that behaviour a bit clearer:

```
int main() {
  printf("process %d: start\n", getpid());
  int r1 = fork();
  printf("process %d: first fork() returned %d\n", getpid(), r1);
  int r2 = fork();
  printf("process %d: second fork() returned %d\n", getpid(), r2);
}
```

On my system, it outputs the following:

```
process 12953: start
process 12953: first fork() returned 12954
process 12954: first fork() returned 0
process 12953: second fork() returned 12955
process 12955: second fork() returned 0
process 12954: second fork() returned 12956
process 12956: second fork() returned 0
```